# How do I force a refresh on an Observable service in Angular2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In `ngOnInit`, my component obtains a list of users like so:

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
});
```

And the implementation of userService.getUsers() looks like this:

```
getUsers() : Observable<UserModel[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user')
                    .map((res: Response) => <UserModel[]>res.json().result)
                    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal error occurred'));
}
```

Now, in another component, I have a form that can create a new user.  The problem is that when I use that second component to create a user, the first component doesn't know that it should make a new GET request to the backend to refresh its view of users.  How can I tell it to do so?

I know that ideally I'd want to skip that extra HTTP GET request, and simply append the data the client already has from when it made the POST to insert the data, but I'm wondering how it'd be done in the case where that's not possible for whatever reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order for an observable to be able to provide values after initial Http observable was completed, it can be provided by RxJS subject. Since caching behaviour is desirable, `ReplaySubject` fits the case.

It should be something like

```
class UserService {
  private usersSubject: Subject;
  private usersRequest: Observable;
  private usersSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.usersSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
  }

  getUsers(refresh: boolean = false) {
    if (refresh || !this.usersRequest) {
      this.usersRequest = this.http.get(...).map(res => res.json().result);

      this.usersRequest.subscribe(
        result => this.usersSubject.next(result),
        err => this.usersSubject.error(err)
      );
    }

    return this.usersSubject.asObservable();
  }
  onDestroy() {
    this.usersSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Since the subject already exists, a new user can be pushed without updating the list from server:

```
this.getUsers().take(1).subscribe(users => 
  this.usersSubject.next([...users, newUser])
)
```

Comment: Lots of great answers here.  I went with the approach you suggested, and it's working great.

Comment: how to unsubscribe using this method ?

Comment: The same way as it would be done with any other observable; use `this.usersSubject.unsubscribe()` or save a subscription from observable and call `unsubscribe` on it in service `ngOnDestroy`. Since Http results in completed observables, there may be no need to unsubscribe, though it would be better to do that.

Comment: by tring the solution i got this error `Generic type 'Subject<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: @IlyesGHOMRANI This is likely specific to later RxJS version. If this is the case, provide type argument like the error suggests, e.g. `foo: Subject<FooType>`.

Comment: It's not good practise to subscribe to observable in services. I would instead use pipe and tap: `this.usersRequest = this.http.get(...).pipe(map(...), tap((result) => this.usersSubject.next(result), switchMap(() => this.usersSubject.asObservable()));`

Comment: @xaunlopez I'd not say it's a bad practice, but it's a good practice to unsubscribe. See my comment above on subscriptions. The code you suggested looks fine but from my understanding of how you suggest it to use, the intention differs. Since an observable can be resubscribed by consumers, the service will do unnecessary requests again, while still returning cached data via `usersSubject`. If you have ideas how it can cache without making requests when no `refresh` is provided, consider posting an answer with derived code.

Comment: @estus my snippet was just to give an idea (as it's not a complete snippet) of replacing the block within `if (refresh || !this.usersRequest)`, not to replace the whole method, otherwise, of course the caching is lost. If I get some spare time I will post a full answer. 

Ok maybe it's not a documented bad practise ;) but from my experience and readings it makes for cleaner code when `.subscribe()` are left out of services. Once you get use to using operators like tap, switchMap, concatMap, and flatMap, you never need to anyway. Just my advice :)

Comment: @xaunlopez I understand which kind of `subscribe` cases you mean. Yes, it would be better to start a request with `getUsers().subscribe(...)`. I don't remember the concerns I had in mind when I wrote this, but I'm positive that the same caching behaviour cannot be expressed only with operators you listed. `subscribe` is perfectly ok for low-level things, it's widely used in RxJS internals. I suppose this could be achieved in more elegant way with `multicast` and `connect` but didn't test that.

Comment: an `Observable` can use async pipes ( i.e.  `... | async` in template files) which eliminates the boilerplate of the `subscribe` and `ubsubscribe` bookkeeping. - Which leads me to the question, can a `ReplaySubject` use async pipes ?

Comment: @bvdb A subject is observable so yes, it can be unsubscribed automatically by a pipe if a subscription is done on it. In current example there are multiple subjects to make this work as intended, notice that it's usersRequest that is unsubscribed manually, not  usersSubject (replay subject). It needs to be unsubscribed once on service destroy.

Comment: @estus I have a form that can edit as well as create a new user. How would I 'patch' the edited user into the list?

Comment: @dak As for the code that was posted in the answer, `this.usersSubject.next([...users, newUser])` is replaced with ``this.usersSubject.next(users)`, where `users` has been previously modified according to your needs. I cannot say how this should be done in your case because it depends on details of your implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've handled this problem so far has been to use an intermediary.  this.userService.getUsers() returns an [Rx.BehviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) which is initialized on the return of the http observable.

Something close to this:

```
getUsers() : BehaviorSubject<UserModel[]> {
  return this.behaviorSubject;
}
updateUsers() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user')
                    .map((res: Response) => <UserModel[]>res.json().result)
                    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal error occurred'))
                    .subscribe((value) => {
                      this.behaviorSubject.next(value)});
}
```

Comment: This is technically the simplest possible 'redux' store :-) Same concept.

Comment: This is a bit out of scope for this question perhaps, but ... Does a behaviorSubject work with an async pipe ?

Comment: @bvdb woah, a dead comment resurrection. Behavior Subject should work with an async pipe.  Been quite a while since I've worked in Angular but based on this comment chain on an issue with Rx Subject, behavior subjects work fine with async pipe. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12129