# Handle errors in a Resolve service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Say I have a `ValuesComponent` that displays an array of `Value` in an HTML table.

```
// in value.ts
export class Value { ... }
```

```js
// in values.component.ts
@Component(...)
export class ValuesComponent { ... }
```

Being a good programmer and all, I've created a different class that is responsible for providing values. Let's call it the `ValuesService`.

```js
// in values.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class ValuesService
{
    public getValues(): Observable<Value[]>
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Suppose that the service gets its values from a web service: `/api/values`

Now instead of injecting the service directly into my component, I want to let the Angular router pre-fetch the values before navigating to the component.

For that, I created a `Resolve` service class and plugged it into the router module.

```js
// in values-resolver.service.ts
export class ValuesResolverService implements Resolve<Value[]> {
    constructor(private backend: ValuesService) {
    }

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Value[]> {
        return this.backend.getValues();
    }
}
```

```js
// In app.module.ts (in @NgModule())
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([{
    path: 'values',
    component: ValuesComponent,
    resolve: { values: ValuesResolverService }
  }])
]
```

```js
// In values.component.ts
public values: Value[];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.values = route.data.values as Value[];
}
```

How am I doing so far? Good? Then where do I put my error handling for when `ValuesService.getValues()` fails? (connection error, internal server error, ...)

When a user tries to navigate to the `/#/values` route and an error occurs, I want to log the error to the console and stop navigation. Ideally, I'd like to redirect the user to the `/#/error` route (not shown in the example code).

Comment: The question doesn't mention what exactly should happen on error.

Comment: A simple `console.log` is fine. I just need to know where to put it and what to return (if anything).

Comment: Then the question is about observables, not resolvers. It's `return this.backend.getValues().catch(...)`.

Comment: @estus see updated question. Also, I know how to work with observables and `catch()`, but I can't return `void` from `catch()` and I don't know what I should return instead to satisfy the router.

Comment: If you need to log, use `.catch((err) => { console.log(err); throw err })`. If you need a redirect, use `.catch((err) => router.navigate(['/error']))` .

Comment: Why `throw err`? That shows up as an uncaught exception.

Comment: Because `catch` catches an error. It should rethrow it if you don't want to proceed with route with bad result.

Comment: Throwing an exception in `resolve` to stop navigation is undocumented behavior. It seems to be an unintended side effect.

Comment: It doesn't 'stop' navigation. It prevents `catch` from resuming navigation. Sure, it will output an uncaught exception, as well as the absence of `catch`, because it is uncaught exception. Do you have problems with `.catch((err) => router.navigate(['/error']))`?

Comment: No, using `navigate` works fine. Just now wondering if there is also a way to cancel navigation without using `navigate` or throwing an exception in `resolve`.

Comment: Errors from resolvers can be caught with `router.navigate(['/values']).catch(...)`. For navigation cancelling CanActivate may be used, but I'm not sure how to get a resolver instance from there.

Comment: I think that `CanActivate` is evaluated *before* the resolver is invoked, so that's a dead end. And I think that manually invoking the resolver inside `CanActivate` is an ugly hack that will result in the same data being resolved twice for the happy path. (once manually, then again by the router)

Comment: CanActivate not just runs before resolvers, but more important, resolvers shouldn't run before it completes, to my knowledge. However, it is possible to use this recipe if both resolver and CanActivate wrap caching http service like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40250950/3731501) (this won't be a hack).

Comment: I've the same problem so i created a new Angular2 ticket
[https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13873](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13873)

Comment: Obviously, you have probably thought of this but you probably need to return a `Promise`, an `Observable` or some other monadic abstraction from the resolver instead of the array of values itself. That way you can attach error handling inside the resolver and, by injecting the router into it as well, you can trigger navigation in `.catch`. Actually, it looks like you are returning an `Observable<Value[]>` so you can attach error handling in the call to `ValuesService` and then redirect in the catch block. I think this will work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I did not think about that. You should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In such a situation, the Service should handle the error, and redirect to the wanted route. The catch method should then return an empty Observable (for the resolve guard to resolve), while handling empty cases during within the resolve.

Something like this

```
export class ValuesService {
    constructor(private http:Http, private router:Router) {}

    getValue() {
       this.http.get('/some/url').map((response:Response) => {
           // Map your response to a model here
       }).catch((response:Response) => {
           // Handler case for different status
           this.router.navigate(['/error']);
           return Observable.empty();
       })
    }
}
```

And the guard to be like the following

```
export class ValueResolveGuard implements Resolve<Value[]> {

    constructor(private valueService:ValueService) {}

    resolve() { // You don't need the route & state if you're not gonna use them
        this.valueService.getValue().toPromise().then((values:Values[]) => {
            if (!values) { // For the Observable.empty() case
                // return some default stuff
            }
            return values;
        })
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to specifically return an observable (shouldn't make any difference in this case, since the resolve guard, accepts both an observable and a promise), you can do something like this.

```
 this.valueService.getValue().first().catch({} => { 
      // return some default value.
 });
```

Notice that first() is required, so that the observable returned would be a terminated observable, otherwise the resolve guard wouldn't resolve. The catch is needed because a first() call on an empty observable would throw an error.

Comment: I disagree with letting the service handle navigation in general, but especially with navigation as a side effect of a failing getter. I prefer my getters to be free of side effects.

Comment: I think it all boils down to how the service is used. A service should be a point of common functionality. If it is expected that on error, the route should  always be updated, then I do think it is the right place to do.

In the case that the service is called multiple times, from different execution points, and require the same behavior, not placing the same routing within the service would result your code in not being DRY.

You should ask the question, what should be the purpose of this service?  That would help you identify the functionality that is required even better.

Comment: You could extract the `catch` function and put it in a separate file. Then it is easy to reuse anywhere: `.getValues().catch(navigateToErrorPage)`. That's dry enough for my taste.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, this seems like the only way, so what you can do is create a general logger class that has a property observable, which is observed in an error UI component sitting somewhere and call the logger inside the catch block... I personally still use Javascript to inject UI messages, simpler, cleaner, more robust.

Comment: hmmm...doesnt resolve() need to return something? That return statement is async.