# Using Angular2 HTTP Service with caching mecanism

Tags: http, caching, angular, service, observable

I expose an HTTP GET request through a service, and several components are using this data (list of countries). I would like the first component request to actually perform the HTTP GET request to the server and cache the results so the the consequent requests will use the cached data, instead of calling the server again.

Here's my Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Message, SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {Country} from '../../domain/country';
import {Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ReplaySubject} from "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";

@Injectable()
export class ListsService {

  private _listOfCountries:SelectItem[]=[];
  private countries:SelectItem[]=[];

  private options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log("create ListsService");
  }

  /**
   * Get all countries
   */
  getListOfCountries():Observable<SelectItem[]> {
    console.log('this._listOfCountries==');
    console.log(this._listOfCountries);
    let countries$ = this._listOfCountries.length > 0? Observable.of(this._listOfCountries): this.http
      .get(`${environment.backend_url}api/countries`, this.options)
      .map(this.mapCountries)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    return countries$;
  }

  private mapCountries(response:Response):SelectItem[] {
    let countries:Country[] = response.json();
    let selectItems:SelectItem[] = countries.map((c) => {
      return {label: c.frLabel, value: c.id}
    });
    this._listOfCountries = selectItems.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
    console.log('this._listOfCountries==');
    console.log(this._listOfCountries);
    return selectItems;
  }

  private handleError(error:any) {
    let errorMsg = error.message || `Error during retrieving data from the API`;
    return Observable.throw(errorMsg);
  }
}
```

I'm injecting my service on components like Below:

```
constructor(
              private listService:ListsService,
              private router: Router,
              public fb:FormBuilder) {
...
}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.listService.getListOfCountries().subscribe(countries => {
      console.log(countries);
      this.listOfCountries = countries;
    });
}
```

I'm declaring the Service only on my root module app.module.ts like below:

```
...
import {ListsService} from "./shared/services/lists.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    IntroComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // @angular
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),
    ...
    //app
    AdministrationModule,
  ],
  providers: [MessageService, ListsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm expecting the service to maintain the data in the field `_listOfCountries`but it's always initialized as an empty array so I'm not having the desired behavior.

Anyone can point me how to fix this and suggest the best approach to resolve this issue?

Solution*:
I modified the Service like below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ListsService {

  private countriesSubject: Subject<SelectItem[]>;
  private countriesRequest: Observable<SelectItem[]>;

  private options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});

  constructor(private http:Http) {
    console.log("create ListsService");
    this.countriesSubject = new ReplaySubject<SelectItem[]>(1);
  }

  /**
   * Get all countries
   */
  getListOfCountries(refresh: boolean = false) {
    if (refresh || !this.countriesRequest) {
      this.countriesRequest =  this.http
        .get(`${environment.backend_url}api/countries`, this.options)
        .map(this.mapCountries)
        .catch(this.handleError);

      this.countriesRequest.subscribe(
        result => this.countriesSubject.next(result),
        err => this.countriesSubject.error(err)
      );
    }
    return this.countriesSubject.asObservable();
  }

  private mapCountries(response:Response):SelectItem[] {
    console.log('mapCountries');
    let countries:Country[] = response.json();
    let selectItems:SelectItem[] = countries.map((c) => {
      return {label: c.frLabel, value: c.id}
    });
    return selectItems;
  }
}
```

on my component:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.listService.getListOfCountries().take(1).subscribe(countries => {
      this.listOfCountries = countries;
    });

  }
```

Comment: Check this answer for example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40250950/3731501

Comment: it works with your example.

Comment: can you give me a brief explanation of your solution and why my attempt fails?

Comment: What does 'fails' mean? A plunk that shows that would help.

Comment: I mean this way of caching let countries$ = this._listOfCountries.length > 0? Observable.of(this._listOfCountries): this.http
      .get(`${environment.backend_url}api/countries`, this.options)
      .map(this.mapCountries)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    return countries$;

Answer (score 0):

Your components which use `ListsService` can subscribe to the `Observable`, and then maintain their own cache.

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private countries:SelectItem[]=[];

  constructor(private listsService: ListsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listsService.getListOfCountries()
      .subscribe((countries: SelectItem[]) => {
        this.countries = countries;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the multiple edits.  It was all in my head, its just that my fingers would not comply.

Comment: I'm already subscribing like   ngOnInit() {
  
    this.listService.getListOfCountries().subscribe(countries => {
      console.log(countries);
      this.listOfCountries = countries;
    });

Comment: when I navigate from component that use the service to another component and then return back, the http request is always called.

Comment: Yes, its always called.  The way your service is designed, that means you will always make another round-trip.  If you cache the results in your service, you can avoid that round-trip.  The question of which approach is right depends on your use-case.

Comment: I'm trying to cache the list on my service in this field _listOfCountries if it's not empty I call my server else I return the data _listOfCountries. but _listOfCountries get reinitialized every time I navigate out the component, I'm expecting single instance of the service used on the whole application. I dont want to use localstorage but simple caching solution.

Comment: Sounds like the scope of your service is too low.  Try moving it up closer to the app level so it's not reinstantiated every time you navigate out of and back in to the component.

Comment: it's declared on providers of my root module app.module.ts,