# Rxjs way to let caller know method is complete, and to cache that result

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Long story short: I have an Angular app initializing by calling a service that calls a second, data service. After the middle service receives and processes its data from the data service, it must communicate to the app, via Observable or Subject, that the app can continue to load. I want to short-circuit any subsequent calls to the same method.

```
export class MiddleService {
    private triedOnce = false;
    private isLoadedSubject = new AsyncSubject();

    public loadConfig (): AsyncSubject<any> {
        if (!this.triedOnce) {
            this.isLoadedSubject.next(false);
            this.dataService.getConfiguration(...).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    // do stuff with data
                    this.isLoadedSubject.next(true);
                }
            );

            this.isLoadedSubject.complete();
            this.triedOnce = true;
        }
        return this.isLoadedSubject;
    }
}
```

The first question, I guess, is if using a Subject like this is an anti-pattern or non-standard use. ([Does this apply?](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93))

Secondly, I feel like I should reuse and be able to reuse the `isLoadedSubject` instead of needing a separate boolean. I'm not sure how to do that outside of a subscription and its `complete` callback. The `AsyncSubject` has an `isCompleted` property, but it's private.

Comment: The Rx way is not to do anything at all. Rx is a monadic functional language for a reason. Just use .publish() to convert the hot observable to a cold one.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
export class MiddleService {
   public readonly config$ = this.dataService.getConfiguration(...)
        .pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

This will delay getting the configuration and it will cache it for all subsequent calls.

See also: [Angular 5 caching http service api calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797910/angular-5-caching-http-service-api-calls/49797986#49797986)