# typescript async http get calls inside a for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a cache in my angular/typescript project to prevent repeated http.get() calls to convert a userId into user full name.

dataService returns a list of object, for example object looks like this `{location: 'abc', food: 'abc', userId: 'idA'}`, for display, I want to transform each object to look like this:  `{location: 'abc', food: 'abc', userId: 'idA', fullName: 'John Doe'}`

```
   getEvents(param1){
    const cache = new Map<string, string>();
    this.dataService.getEvents(param1).subscribe(
        async res => { 
            this.eventsData = [];
            for(let item of res.items){
                const key: string = item.userId;
                if(cache.get(key)){
                    item.fullName = cache.get(key);
                }
                else{
                    await this.nameService.getFullName(key).subscribe(
                        res=> {
                            cache.set(key, res);
                            item.fullName = res;
                        }
                    )
                }
                this.eventsData.push(item);
            }
        }
    );       
}
```

The reason that I put `Async,await` is because I want each `item` to be processed sequentially, if second row of data has the same userId, it would do the lookup in the Map, instead of making a call to the nameService.  And I have prior knowledge that for example out of 100 rows of data, it's only a few users.

for a list of size 3 has exactly the same userId, my code above somehow still makes 3 calls to NameService.

And I have tried taking the code block starting at `for()` to `push(item)` out to another function and put await in front of that function, that didn't reduce the number of calls to nameService(which in turn makes a http get call) either. 
What's the issue with my code? and if there is better ways to cache http get calls, please let me know.

I have tried the shareReplay answer in [here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797910/angular-5-caching-http-service-api-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797910/angular-5-caching-http-service-api-calls) But it didn't seem to reduce the number of calls either. maybe I didn't get what the answer meant. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `...subscribe(...)` returns a `Promise`? `subscribe` implies it's an `Observable`, not a Promise, so `await` won't do what you're expecting.

Comment: @Jacob: You should be able to do `.toPromise()` instead of `subscribe(...)`. You can then use `await`